# How to Create a Dynamic Button Control with a Stackpanel and different Button Actions?

Tags: c#, wpf

So, i know how to add Items to a Stackpanel programatically, but how can i assign Buttons to Various actions? I want to create a list of buttons, where the User can upload Custom CSV Files. So the upload procedure for every Button ist the same, only the Filename increases by the Stackpanel count. I don´t quite know what to search for so i´d be glad for some Advise.

Thanks

Comment: Consider using an ItemsControl with a Button in its ItemTemplate. Bind the Button's Command property to an ICommand property of the item class. The ItemsSource of the ItemsControl would be bound to a collection of item objects with different commands.

Comment: I might give this a Try. Thanks